# Parallel computation on a Set of data in java 8?

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, java-8, hazelcast

I have a Set of data like this:

```
Set<CustomObject> testSet = [{id: a1, qty: 3}, 
                             {id: a2, qty: 9},
                             {id: a3, qty: 5},
                             {id: a4, qty: 8},
                             {id: a5, qty: 12},
                             ...
                             {id: a200, qty: 7}];
```

The ids are grouped into 3 groups which can be found using the method:

```
//The getGroup method is implemented in the class CustomObject.
//I am using hazelcast map to store few id's that are inclusive, and
//one of the id that is in the request of the api is the current id.
public String getGroup(String id){
     HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
     if(id.equals(this.id)){
       return "currentId";
     }else if(id.equals(hazelcastInstance.getMap("idMap").get(id))){
       return "inclusive";
     } else {
       return "exclusive";
     }
}
```

The testSet above is with huge data, and I want to perform sum of quantities of each object in the Set based on the grouping method above using Java.

I tried using streams but that doesn't allow me to use the getGroup method in the groupingBy method of Java 8 Streams.

Please guide me on how to efficiently sum the qty values based on groups with parallel processing.

Comment: how do you use grouping by method probably its not working because of id parameter

Comment: Yes @Bolzano, I cant use that here, I was trying to find a way to group the objects based on the method and apply sum method on the groups.

`Map<CustomObject.Type, Integer> sumByType =
     testSet
            .stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                 CustomObject::getGroup,                      
                    Collectors.reducing(
                      0,
                     CustomObject::getQty,
                     Integer::sum)));`

Comment: ok first every getGroup shouldn't create hazelCast instance i'll suggest you any other practice for that but i want to know where do you plan the pass id argument into the getGroup method ?

Comment: I just wanted to highlight the use of hazelcast here, I am actually injecting a bean that would give me the hazelcast instance. I use the bean to check if the id is present in the Map or not.
Coming to the id argument in getGroup method, as you say, I am not sure how to use it in streams. Streams use the object's getter method to access the value and then reduce the qty data using sum method.
I need a similar way, where I do the summation of qty based on groups.

Comment: then according to your code your object's group always be a "currentId", please explain it as detailed, then i'll write the proper code

Comment: I have a service, which takes this Set of data as mentioned above. Along with the Set there is another field called currentId. This currentId is also a part of Set. I need to compute the sum of qty fields of each object based on the group inclusive or exclusive. but currentId is also present in the Set which shouldn't be used in the sum, but its qty should be kept in a separate variable.

Comment: All this computations needs to be done parallel to reduce the time, as my service response time is shooting up the desired complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code will give the inclusive and exclusive qty's sum as grouped.

```java
Map < Object, Integer > resultMap =
    testSet.parallelStream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(item - > {
            if (item.getId().equals(hazelcastInstance.getMap("idMap").get(id)) 
                    return "inclusive";
                else
                    return "exclusive";
            },
            Collectors.summingInt(CustomObject::getQty)));
```

Additionally when using `parallelStream()`, you may consider using `ArrayList` instead of `HashSet` for a better performance, please don't forget to measure it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it out.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. I changed from Set to ArrayList and the performance was even better. Appreciate your help. :)

Comment: it would be nice if you are able to share measure results with set and with ArrayList .

Comment: My compute time has Decreased
using Set it was ~800ms with data of about 250 Objects in Set 
to ~250-300ms with same data using ArrayLists, it was on an i5 Machine using 100 parallel requests at a time.

Comment: You can shorten `stream().parallel()` to `parallelStream()`. Further, `item -> {    if(item.getId().equals(hazelcastInstance.getMap("idMap").get(id))   return "inclusive";  else    return "exclusive";   }` can be simplified to `item -> item.getId().equals( hazelcastInstance.getMap("idMap").get(id))? "inclusive": "exclusive"`